# How to import SQL file which has no N prefix

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, unicode

I have a large **.sql** file in Persian Language. The file is exported from **sqlite db browser** and has no **N** prefix for unicode fields. How can I reuse it in Sql Server?

This is sample of insert query in original file:

```
insert into `words` (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
```

But I need this

```
insert into `words` (id,word) values ('1','2',N'فارسی');
```

I can not use find/replace to replace `,'` with `,N'` because there are  some `,'` which represent number fields and has no need to N prefix.

I think I will need some conversion between multiple software (perhaps Microsoft access?) but I have no idea where to start?

Comment: can you provide the .sql flat file so others can peek into it to get an idea?

Comment: I have added some details to question @Bijujose

Comment: are these lines aligned?

Comment: how about do a replace on every thing as you mentioned like ,' to ,N' and store it into staging table then do a convert and import the required ones. I think that will be the cheapest way to do this.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean from aligned? @Bijujose

Comment: ,if it's aligned we can do a vertical select to add N to it that is why I asked is it aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an answer based on the below layout.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.words(id NVARCHAR(1000),id2 NVARCHAR(1000),word NVARCHAR(max))


INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1','2','فارسی');

**Do replace all for ,' --> ,N'**
```

will become

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.words(id NVARCHAR(1000),id2 NVARCHAR(1000),word NVARCHAR(max))


INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
INSERT into dbo.words (id,word) values ('1',N'2',N'فارسی');
```

The only downside is you have to change all column definition to NVARCHAR(). But worth a try if there are not much tables. Also try to separate the tables and insert code to a seperate file to work out.

NB:Also regarding the alignment. If the insert layout is aligned we can press 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> will enable a vertical select which is quite useful.